# Why is the tub of my Whirlpool Cabrio washer so low?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a Whirlpool Cabrio top-loading washing machine model WTW8540BW0.  The tub seems to be lower than it should be.  There's a gap of 2" or more between the bottom of the top of the washer and the top of the tub.  I've never seen such a large gap on any washer.  My daughter has a slightly different model from the same line and the gap in her washer is much smaller.  We've replaced the suspension rods but it didn't seem to make a difference.

While I suspect it is unrelated, the washer also is quite loud when it spins, including an occasional squeak.  [image: Gap above washer tub]

Comment: How old is the washer? Has it always been low? Have you checked with Whirlpool?

Comment: All makers have design specs for their machines.  They will tell you if that dimension is correct or needs to be adjusted/fixed.  They are the best ones who know.  Similar models probably have different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

The tub is low when water is in it. It returns to usual position when tub is empty.

Comment: What would be the reason for that? Do you have any citations for it?